# Why the method that fires the C# event must be protected virtual?

Tags: c#

While reading a book on C# I found this source code :

```
public class Stock 
{  
    ...  
    public event EventHandler<PriceChangedEventArgs> PriceChanged; 

    protected virtual void OnPriceChanged (PriceChangedEventArgs e)  
    {    
       if (PriceChanged != null) PriceChanged (this, e);  
    } 
}
```

The author states that the standard event pattern requires, I quote :

> The pattern requires that you write a protected virtual method that fires the event. The name must match the name of the event, prefixed with the word On, and then accept a single EventArgs argument:

Why should it be protected and virtual ?

Comment: The word *must* is not accurate. It's just a common pattern, a best practice. Certainly if you have a reason to make that sort of thing public, or are certain you will never want to override it, you don't have to make it protected or virtual at all.

Comment: You use protected to prevent the external world from accessing a member while allowing subclasses to access it, and virtual when you want to allow derived classes to provide their own specialized implementation of the method.

Comment: Bingo. And there is your answer @polskaamoshen. It really is that simple. You use protected so any class that inherits from this class can raise the event (by calling `OnPriceChanged`). And you use virtual so any class that inherits from this class can add their own specialised implementation (maybe they want to show a message to the user before raising the event). The pattern in your book is a nice way to allow a class, and classes that inherit from it, to raise events.

Comment: @mjwills, I see now. It's  just too so straightforward to understand. I was just confused by the usage of the term pattern to express this. Thank you for your patience in ansering a newbie question, and interest .

Comment: Think of `pattern` as a reusable approach to make your life easier. By doing it this way, your life is easier if you ever add a class that inherits from this class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`virtual` means that a class can inherit from `Stock` and override that method.
`protected` means that only `Stock` or classes that inherit from `Stock` can access that method.

Events by themselves don't have to be fired from virtual or protected methods. This is just a pattern that some applications use, which allow derived classes to fire the event as well.

Classes that inherit from `Stock` and override `OnPriceChanged` can call `base. OnPriceChanged` and It would fire the event.

For example,

```cs
class MyStock : Stock
{
    protected override void OnPriceChanged (PriceChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something
        base.OnPriceChanged(e); // will call OnPriceChanged in the base class, and fire the event
    }
}
```

Comment: I see now thank you. This answers the question :).

Answer (score 4):

It's a pattern from the days of "Component-oriented programming" - it's still valid, but 
not as relevant today as Delegate-based events which use the `OnEventName`-pattern aren't as popular because UI programming is either done in JavaScript (thus avoiding .NET entirely) or uses the ViewModel-pattern which doesn't use Delegate events at all.

As an explanation for "why" - let's look at the canonical example of Component-oriented programming: WinForms controls. All controls derive from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` which represents an ecapsulation of a Win32 "`hWnd`" window, which is a 2D surface which accepts Win32 Window Messages for user-input (mouse, keyboard, touch, etc) and paints to itself.

The `Control` class exposes its own initial set of events, like `Load` and `MouseMove`. All of these events are exposed in two ways:

1. Publicly accessible `event` members. Essentially multicast, strongly-typed `Delegate` properties.

   - These are subscribe-only. So a consumer of a component can listen to events, but they cannot invoke events themselves.
   - In C# they look like this:

     ```
     public event DelegateType EventName;
     ```

     For example:

     ```
     public class Control : Component
     {
         public event EventHandler Click;
     }
     ```
2. Methods that invoke each `event` (by invoking the multicast `Delegate`).

   - These methods are not `public` because that would break encapsulation (i.e. you don't want a consumer to be able to raise events), so they can be either `private` or `protected`.
   - By choosing `protected` instead of `private` means that subclasses can invoke events themselves, if appropriate.
   - In C# they look like this:

     ```
     public class Control : Component
     {
         public event EventHandler Click;

         protected virtual void OnClick(EventArgs e)
         {
             this.Click?.Invoke( this, e ); 
         }

         private void OnWin32WindowMessage( Message m )
         {
             switch( m.EventId )
             {
                 case Win32.MouseClick:
                     this.OnClick( EventArgs.Empty );
                     break;
                 case Win32.MouseMove:
                     this.OnMouseMove( EventArgs.Empty );
                     break;
                 case Win32.KeyDown:
                     this.OnKeyDown( EventArgs.Empty );
                     break;
                 // etc
             }
         }
     }
     ```

You can argue that if a component subclass only wants to subscribe to events belonging to its superclass then it should not be able to invoke certain events themselves and so the `On{EventName}` methods should be `private` and not `protected` - and the subclass should set-up an `EventHandler` inside its constructor. Like so:

```
public class MySubclass : Control
{
    public MySubclass()
    {
        this.Click += new EventHandler( this.Clicked );
    }

    private void Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show( "boop!" );
    }
}
```

...and this is valid.

However, there are at least three reasons for using `protected virtual` methods instead of `private`:

1. The advantage to using `virtual` methods is that it lets the subclass override the behaviour.

   - For example, if the superclass has a trivial `OnClick` method that simply (and always) invokes the `Click` `event` but you want your subclass to only allow the `Click` `event` to be invoked if `this.Disabled == true`):

     ```
     public class MySubclass : Control
     {
         protected override OnClick( EventArgs e )
         {
             if( !this.Disabled )
             {
                 base.OnClick( e );
             } 
         }

         public Boolean Disabled { get; set; }
     }
     ```
2. Allowing subclasses to be notified first.

   - Multicast delegates in C# do not offer any control over the precise order-of-execution - by using `virtual` methods this allows a subclass to always be notified first, before any external consumers. This is important if the state of `MySubclass` will change in an event-handler. For example:

     ```
     public class MySubclass : Control
     {
         public MySubclass()
         {
             this.Click += new EventHandler( this.Clicked );
         }

         private void Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             this.BackgroundColor = Colors.Red;
         }
     }

     public class MyForm : Form
     {
         private readonly MySubclass sc;

         public MyForm()
         {
             this.sc = new MySubclass();
             this.Controls.Add( this.sc );

             this.sc.Click += new EventHandler( this.SCClicked );
         }

         private void SCClicked (Object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             MessageBox.Show( "The control's colour is " + this.sc.BackgroundColor );
         }
     }
     ```

     As it's possible for `MyForm.SCClicked` to run before `MySubclass.Clicked`, `SCClicked` may report the old colour, not the new colour.

     By using a `virtual` method `override` this can be avoided:

     ```
     public class MySubclass : Control
     {
         protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
         {
             this.BackgroundColor = Colors.Red;

             base.OnClick( e );
         }
     }

     public class MyForm : Form { /* unchanged */ }
     ```

...and it will now work as-expected.

3. The other reason is performance.

   - Delegates are more expensive than a `virtual` method call. So by overriding the method means a subclass can subscribe to an event with less runtime overhead than using an `event`-handler.
   - While this isn't important for one-off events like `Load` or maybe even `Paint` and `Click`, it can matter if it's a high-frequency event (think: thousands of times per second).
   - Performance can matter, even on today's computers that are 10-50x faster than the late-1990s machines that were around when .NET and WinForms was originally designed. Especially as event-handling code in WinForms has to run in the UI thread.
   - Today, high-frequency events tend to use the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) instead of Delegate events, precisely because that avoids the overhead of using delegates (the linked Wikipedia article does describe C#'s `event` support as an example of the Observer pattern, which is strictly true - but when people talk about the Observer pattern they usually mean something like Reactive programming: http://reactivex.io/